# VB Net - Is it possible call a function before complete loaded program?

Tags: vb.net

I'm new on Vb net, I confused how to call function before complete loaded program, on python it's simple

```
def Test():
  print 1

Test() #and it will print 1
```

but how on vb ?
I already test

```
Public Class Form2
    Function Main_Func()
        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
        ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0
        TextBox1.Text = "Hello World"
    End Function
Main_Func()
End Class
```

but it showing error, any one can help me ?

Comment: you cant reference controls on a form that either a) does not exist yet or b) has not been instanced yet.  So tentatively no, not if you want to work with controls but yes if you start from Sub Main and need to have classes do some stuff.

Comment: you can try using a Messagebox.Show or Debug.WriteLine if you want to see the values before you load the controls. Those would be equivalent. What you are doing is saying, "before I even create a textbox1, I want to assign it's value." You can't do that.

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to accomplish. What do you mean by complete loaded program?

Comment: What is the "Error" that it is showing?

Comment: Do it on the load event before anything else or the constructor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the designer, double-click on the form's title bar. This will take you to the code for the form with a ready-made Form_Load method into which you can type the code you showed:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
    ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0
    TextBox1.Text = "Hello World"
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think you will see the result until after the form has completed the Load event, which is by definition when the form has fully loaded. Note these comments are for WinForms.

Comment: @rheitzman [Form.Load Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): "Occurs before a form is displayed for the first time." Perhaps you are thinking of the Form.Shown event?

Comment: Thanks this is what I mean, sorry my english so bad

Comment: My impression of the occurrence of WinForm events: New, Load, Shown. The program could be fully "loaded" IMO in Load or Shown. Note that if you use a MsgBox (for example in a Try..Catch) before the shown event the form will not be visible on the screen. That may be desired as you can short circuit the "load" end exit before the form is shown. Things can be made more complicated with bound controls.